# У меня есть картинка на всю ширину экрана?

Tags: bootstrap

У меня есть картинка на всю ширину экрана. Как сделать чтобы чтобы когда я уменьшаю экран она не теряла свою высоту а только обрезалась по ширине и сделать текст что внизу должен располагаться на картинки. Всё написано на bootstrap 4

```css
.img_back{
 overflow: hidden;
}

.img_back img {
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Hello, world!</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="img_back">
  <img src="images/img_back_header.png">
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h1 class="dolg_h1">Взыскание долгов</h1>
  <p class="col-8 text_head mx-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1:

```css
.img_back{
 overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img_back:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.img_back img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
}

.intro .container-fluid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  
<div class="intro">
  <div class="img_back">
    <img src="https://hdwallsource.com/img/2014/5/images-26825-27541-hd-wallpapers.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1 class="dolg_h1">Взыскание долгов</h1>
    <p class="col-8 text_head mx-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2 с фоном (на всякий случай):

```css
.intro:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.intro {
  background: url(https://hdwallsource.com/img/2014/5/images-26825-27541-hd-wallpapers.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.intro .container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  
<div class="intro">  
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1 class="dolg_h1">Взыскание долгов</h1>
    <p class="col-8 text_head mx-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```